# Is there a function in R to equalize the length of right and left channel after downsampling an audio file?

Tags: r

My wave file is very large and therefore I downsampled it. However, after downsampling, the length of the right channel has no elements.
Below is the code I used to downsample the audio file

`a=resamp(a,f=48000,g=1025,output = "Wave")`

```
 str(a)
Formal class 'Wave' [package "tuneR"] with 6 slots
  ..@ left     : int [1:623310] 162 140 -99 77 96 -5 -38 155 -125 89 ...
  ..@ right    : num(0) 
  ..@ stereo   : logi FALSE
  ..@ samp.rate: num 1025
  ..@ bit      : num 16
  ..@ pcm      : logi TRUE
```

Comment: You have downsampled to mono. Was your initial file in stereo? The `resamp` function only seems to perform single-channel re sampling (left channel by default, though can be switched to right). Perhaps resample both channels?

Comment: @AllanCameron, yes the initial file was in stereo. Please do you suggest resampling each channel independently? If yes is there a script to resample channels?